# JS Notification Windows doesn't really work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically we're relatively new to this and I don't know what to google to fix this problem. Whenever i want to restart the level it just refers me back to the prompt again, which isn't really optimal (Guess everyone can figure that out) but when I click on abbrechen (cancel) it just gives me an error. for that reason im thinking about just doing it another way but I hope there's a way to fix this. images code and whatever should be included idk maybe.
Also there are plenty of things wrong with our game like the fact that there's a border we want to like stretch since it just cuts off if you go out too far yeaaa whatever if you can help just say anything.[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg6rq.png)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu0BX.png)

```js
(function () {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    width = 1000,
    height = 400,
    player = {
        x: width / 2,
        y: 200,
        width: 25,
        height: 25,
        speed: 3,
        velX: 0,
        velY: 0,
        jumping: false,
        grounded: false,
        color:'#FFCC99'
    },
    keys = [],
    friction = 0.8,
    gravity = 0.4,
    boxes = [],
    powerup = [];  

powerup.push({ //red box right
        x: 810,
        y: 250,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        color: '#BF4D28',
        effect: 'shrink'
    });
powerup.push({ //red box in center
        x: 395,
        y:75,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        color: '#BF4D28',
        effect: 'gravity'
    });
powerup.push({ //dreieck links
        x: -10,
        y: 88,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        color: '#222',
        effect: 'tele',
        rotate: 20,
        px: 20,//where they get teleported
        py: 370,
        stay: true
    });
powerup.push({
        x: 60,
        y: 365,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        color: '#2A5D77',
        effect: 'win',
        stay: true
    });

// dimensions
boxes.push({//unteri linki wand
    x: 0,
    y: height/4+10,
    width: 10,
    height: height,
    color: 'green'
});
boxes.push({//Oberi linki wand
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 10,
    height: height/4-15,
    color: 'green'
});
boxes.push({//box for the ground
    x: 0,
    y: height - 10,
    width: width,
    height: 50,
    color: 'orange'
});
boxes.push({//box on right
    x: width - 10,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: height,
    color: 'yellow'
});
boxes.push({//dach
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 1000,
    height: 10,
    color: 'blue'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 290,
    y: 200,
    width: 300,
    height: 10,
    color: 'blue'
});
boxes.push({//unischtbari wand block
    x: 380,
    y: 135,
    width: 90,
    height: 10,
    color: 'black'
});
boxes.push({ //oberi rechti wand
    x: 375,
    y: 55,
    width: 10,
    height: 90,
    color: 'blue'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 120,
    y: 250,
    width: 140,
    height: 10,
    color: 'red'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 220,
    y: 300,
    width: 80,
    height: 10,
    color: 'black'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 340,
    y: 340,
    width: 90,
    height: 10,
    color: '#655643'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 740,
    y: 300,
    width: 160,
    height: 10,
    color: '#655643'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 0,
    y: 350,
    width: 90,
    height: 10,
    color: '#000000'
});
boxes.push({
    x: 90,
    y: 350,
    width: 10,
    height: 50,
    color: '#000000'
});

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

function update() {
    // check keys
    if (keys[38] || keys[32] || keys[87]) {
        // up arrow or space
        if (!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
            player.jumping = true;
            player.grounded = false;
            player.velY = -player.speed * 2.5;//how high to jump
        }
    }
    if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {
        // right arrow
        if (player.velX < player.speed) {
            player.velX++;
        }
    }
    if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {
        // left arrow
        if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
            player.velX--;
        }
    }
  
    

    player.velX *= friction;
    player.velY += gravity;

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    
    player.grounded = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {//print boxes
        ctx.fillStyle = boxes[i].color;
        ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
        
        var dir = colCheck(player, boxes[i]);

        if (dir === "l" || dir === "r") {
            player.velX = 0;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if (dir === "b") {
            player.grounded = true;
            player.jumping = false;
        } else if (dir === "t") {
            player.velY *= -1;
        }

    }
    
    if(player.grounded){
         player.velY = 0;
    }
    
    player.x += player.velX;
    player.y += player.velY;
  
    ctx.fill();//Draw charater stuff
    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
    
    //draw powerup stuff 
    for(var j = 0; j < powerup.length; j++){
      ctx.save();
      var cx = powerup[j].x + 0.5 * powerup[j].width,   // x of shape center
      cy = powerup[j].y + 0.5 * powerup[j].height; //y of shape center
      ctx.translate(cx, cy);  //translate to center of shape
      ctx.rotate( (Math.PI / 180) * 45);//rotate 25 degrees.
      if(powerup[j].effect  === 'tele'){
        ctx.rotate( (Math.PI / 180) * powerup[j].rotate);//rotate 25 degrees.
        powerup[j].rotate = (Math.PI / 180) * powerup[j].rotate;
      }
      ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);            //translate center back to 0,0
      ctx.fillStyle = powerup[j].color;
      ctx.fillRect(powerup[j].x, powerup[j].y, powerup[j].width, powerup[j].height);
      ctx.restore();
      
      //powerup collision
      if(colCheck(player, powerup[j])!==null){//touched power up!
        if(powerup[j].effect==='gravity'){
          gravity= 0.4;//decrease gravity
          player.speed = 4 ;
        }
        else if (powerup[j].effect==='shrink'){
          player.width= 10;
          player.height= 10;
          player.speed = 5;
        }
        else if (powerup[j].effect==='tele'){
          player.x=powerup[j].px;
          player.y=powerup[j].py;
        }
        else if (powerup[j].effect==='win'){
          var r = confirm("Du hast gewonnen! Willst du nochmal spielen?");
          if (r == false) {
               player.x=200;
               player.y=200;
          } else {
               window.location.href = window.location.href;
          }
        }
        if(powerup[j].stay!==true)
        powerup[j].width=0;//make power up go away
      }
    }
    //powerup stuff

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
    // get the vectors to check against
    var vX = (shapeA.x + (shapeA.width / 2)) - (shapeB.x + (shapeB.width / 2)),
        vY = (shapeA.y + (shapeA.height / 2)) - (shapeB.y + (shapeB.height / 2)),
        // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
        hWidths = (shapeA.width / 2) + (shapeB.width / 2),
        hHeights = (shapeA.height / 2) + (shapeB.height / 2),
        colDir = null;

    // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
    if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {
        // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)
        var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),
            oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);
        if (oX >= oY) {
            if (vY > 0) {
                colDir = "t";
                shapeA.y += oY;
            } else {
                colDir = "b";
                shapeA.y -= oY;
            }
        } else {
            if (vX > 0) {
                colDir = "l";
                shapeA.x += oX;
            } else {
                colDir = "r";
                shapeA.x -= oX;
            }
        }
    }
    return colDir;
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});


window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    update();
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);

body{
  background: linear-gradient(#87CEEB, #808080);
}

h1{
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height:1em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  @media{
    
  }
}

p{
  line-height: 10em;
}

div{
  color: #000000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height:10px;
  margin:2%;
}

#canvas{
      margin-left:500%;/*spielbreite*/
    background: linear-gradient(#87CEEB, #808080); 
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
```

Comment: _"it just gives me an error"_ What error?

Comment: I cant really send an image but ill just do it like this,
404
That page doesn't exist.
i think theres also the code included in my post so if you want you can just execute that, finish the game click on Ok if the prompt shows up and then on cancel. Thats what im trying to fix